# convert column arrays to array of row objects

Tags: arrays, json, object, jq, transpose

i have a json file representing a table with two columns.

the Column values are in an array

`{
'columnA':[1,2,3],
'columnB':[6,7,8]
}`

i need to convert it to an array of rows:

`[
{'columnA':1, 'columnB':6},
{'columnA':2, 'columnB':7},
{'columnA':3, 'columnB':8},
]`

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Pure JSON doesn't take single quotes for key fields

Comment: `transpose` results in an error: Cannot index object with number

forcing string keys with `to_entries` or even `map(to_entries)` didnt lead to anything usefull yet

`map` will only itterate one column and not result in any key access to the second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
[range(0; .columnA|length) as $i
 | {columnA: .columnA[$i], columnB: .columnB[$i]}]
```

And here's another that is keyname-neutral and should work for any number of "columns":

```
def objectify($template):
  . as $in
  | ($template|keys_unsorted) as $k
  | reduce range(0; $k|length) as $i (null; . + {($k[$i]): $in[$i]});

. as $in
| [.[]]
| transpose
| map(objectify($in))
```

Comment: Thank you. there are many answers that lead to the same result. accepting this one as it was the first.

Answer (score 1):

Use `transpose` builtin:

```
[ [{columnA: .columnA[]}],
  [{columnB: .columnB[]}]
] | transpose | map(add)
```

Comment: Thank you. there are many answers that lead to the same result. I've accepted the first one, though i like this approach!

Answer (score 1):

i figured it out:

`[.columnA,.columnB] | transpose | map({"columnA":.[0], "columnB": .[1]})`

1. Convert to array of arrays
2. transpose
3. convert back to objects